# hibernate restrictions and/or order

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

small questions about Restrictions.or and Restrictions.and

If I do something like this:

```
...
criterion = criterionA;
criterion = Restrictions.and(criterion, criterionB);
criterion = Restrictions.or(criterion, criterionC);
criterion = Restrictions.and(criterion, criterionD);
```

Will this be treated as:

```
(A and B) or (C and D) (following mathematical conventions)
```

Or will it be treated in the order it the restrictions have been added:

```
(((A and B) or C) and D)
```

Please also add references if there are any...

Comment: You are really mixing up things when you re-assign "criterion" in every line. Consider using final in your variable declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be treated as the latter

```
(((A and B) or C) and D)
```

You could do

```
criterion = Restriction.or(Restrictions.and(criterionA, criterionB), Restrictions.and(criterionC, criterionD))
```

If you want the first solution

Answer (score 2):

there are no precedence rules (like in a programming language or in a CFG parser), method calls order unambiguously determines the expression.

(A and B) or (C and D) must be translated to:

```
import static org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions.*;
...
criterion = or(and(A, B), and(C,D));
```